# Can I prevent the user of a restricted system from minimizing my application?

Tags: windows, kotlin, jetbrains-compose, kotlin-desktop

I have a Kotlin + Jetbrains Compose desktop application. This application will be used in a specific computer, that is only supposed to run this application and the software that the application runs through subprocesses.

Needless to say, this application will not be made available for the general public or "normal" computers, it's a dedicated machine for this application alone and I needed to make sure that the user of this computer (That needs to have Windows as its main OS) will not use it for other purposes. I'm able to prevent the user from closing my application with the normal means (clicking 'x': I disabled the program's response to that button and left it in fullscreen and undecorated, just to make sure.
And if my application crashes, the computer will be restarted, and the application reopened as the first UI action possible.

Is there a way to capture or prevent/block user attempts to switch context from my application? Attempts like:

- Alt + Tab
- Win + Tab
- Win + D
- any other Win combination that opens "dangerous" prompts such as Win + R for "Execute"

I tried capturing the keys combination from the Compose `onKeyEvent` for the `application`, but the OS has precedence over the command, I believe...

Can I disable that somehow? Is it even possible? Maybe at the OS level? I would have total access to the OS when installing and configuring the unit. Sorry for the kind of philosophical question, but I really needed to figure this out and I'm running out of ideas.

Maybe using some kind of Kiosk mode? I have no idea...

Comment: have you checked [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app)?